# Why .NET exceptions are mutable?

Tags: .net, exception, throw

I'm wondering why .NET exceptions classes from Base Class Library has some mutable members by default

- Why I can change the `Source`, `HelpLink` and values from `Data`, but can't change anything else like the `Message`?
- Why throwing the exception rewrites the `StackTrace` making it mutable too? Is appending the stack trace information to existing trace would be better design (but still mutable)?
- What possible improvements in .NET exceptions design may be?

I'm interesting just in design choices...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `StackTrace` makes sense to me, at least. The idea is that an `Exception` (as an object) may be passed around, returned from methods, etc. The `StackTrace` is only important as an exception is thrown and caught. In a sense, `StackTrace` is really more of a property of the *throwing* of the exception, not the `Exception` object itself.

Regarding the mutability of the other properties, I assume it is just because it's easier to construct an instance by assigning to properties rather than forcing them all into the constructor. Remember that at the time `Exception` was designed, C# did not have optional parameters.

You could consider a re-design where `Exception` and derived classes are immutable, but this would require an exception factory or builder class. It would just make deriving from `Exception` that much more complex.

Comment: ok, if the problem is the passing a lot of data into exception, why the `Message` property is readonly?

Comment: `Message` is the one non-optional piece of information, so it makes sense to put it in the constructor.